# Extrabold Font weight for pdf sharp

Tags: fonts, pdfsharp

I am using the Open Sans font in a Pdf. I need to use the Open Sans Extrabold Italic style. In pdf sharp there is a BoldItalic XFontStyle, but no Extrabold, how do I set the font to be Extrabold in pdf sharp. This is the code that I am using:

```
XFont extrabold = new XFont("Open Sans", 80, XFontStyle.BoldItalic);
```

I am looking for something like `XFont extrabold = new XFont("Open Sans", 80, XFontStyle.ExtraboldItalic);` but this does not exist.

I have found that there is an XFontWeights.ExtraBold setting, but I am not sure how to use this in an XFont.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the font name "Open Sans Extrabold" (not "Open Sans") and the normal font style italic.

There is also "Open Sans Light" and "Open Sans Semibold" for other font weights.